# GTT row not found on delete but found on insert

Tags: java, sql, oracle, temp-tables, dml

I have never used GTT under Oracle and Java.

I want to use it to manage some datas, I want to add some forecasting of products and I wish to remove any existing row before inserting looking it by ID

Here is my GTT

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE "M_PRODUCT_FORECAST" 
   (    
    "M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FORECAST_MODE" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'D' NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FORECAST_QTY" NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CHECK (forecast_mode IN ('D','P')) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_KEY" PRIMARY KEY ("M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_ID", "FORECAST_MODE") ENABLE
   ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

Then here is my Java code

```
private void addProductToForecast() {

        Integer     productId       = (Integer) productSearchEditor.getValue();
        BigDecimal  qty             = qtyNumberBox.getValue();
        String      mode            = developementCheckbox.isSelected()?"D":"P";

        PreparedStatement   ps                          = null;
        try {

            String deletePreviousForcastIfExists =    " DELETE FROM  "+M_PRODUCT_FORECAST
                                                    + "        WHERE "+M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_ID+" = ? "
                                                    + "        AND   "+FORECAST_MODE+"         = ?";
            
            ps = DB.prepareStatement(deletePreviousForcastIfExists, null);
            ps.setInt(1, productId);
            ps.setString(2, mode);
            int update = ps.executeUpdate();

            log.info(deletePreviousForcastIfExists + "return update value :: "+update);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            Util.closeCursor(ps,null);
            ps = null; 
        }
        
        try {
            String insertIntoForcast = " INSERT INTO " +M_PRODUCT_FORECAST
                    +" VALUES(?,?,?)";
            
            ps = DB.prepareStatement(insertIntoForcast, null);
            ps.setInt(1, productId);
            ps.setString(2, mode);
            ps.setBigDecimal(3, qty);
            int update = ps.executeUpdate();
            log.info(insertIntoForcast + "return update value :: "+update);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Util.closeCursor(ps, null);
            ps = null;
        }
        
    }
```

**NB**

While debugging the first remove update value return 0, I guess this means it doesn't find any row to be deleted, **however** the insert is rising the violation of unique key exception which means there is data.

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: violation de contrainte unique (M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_KEY)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest to use `merge` instead of `delete`+`insert`:

```sql
merge into M_PRODUCT_FORECAST m
using (
   select :id as id, 
          :mode as mode, 
          :qty as qty 
   from dual) n
on (m.M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_ID = n.id and m.FORECAST_MODE = n.mode)
when matched then update
     set m.M_PRODUCT_FORECAST_ID = n.mode
when not matched then
     insert
     values (n.id,n.mode,n.qty)
```

In addition, I would check what exactly is coming into db. I mean bind variables and their types, just to confirm that there is no implicit datatype conversion or something like that